# Getting Json objects into html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have some difficulties with getting these Json objects to show .

```
<section class="hero" style="background-image: url(./images/hero.png)">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row row-big">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipiscing elit
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-small">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipiscing elit
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!--Icon missing instead of img--><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-image: url ('./images/button_arrow_white.png')">Sign up now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my Json

```
var json = '{"row":{"col":{"title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit"}}}'

$(document).ready(function(){

//Json
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

mainDivData(obj);

function mainDivData(obj){

    /* for (i in obj.popNav.popLinks){

        var j = parseInt(i)+1;
        $('.pop-links:nth-child('+ j +').txt').text(obj.popNav.popLinks[i].txt);
    } */

    /* for (i in obj.row.colTwelve) {
        $('.news-title').text(obj.row.colTwelve[i].title);
    } */

    //THIS ONE 
    for (i in obj.row.col){
        $('.col-10.title').text(obj.row.col[i].title);
    }

}
```

I tried many times with different loops but it is always the same. 
I can't seem to find my mistake. When I delete the text from the HTML , i get nothing. Any advice?

Comment: it's an object not an array you don't need any loops obj.row.col.title will get your title. Assuming you're going to have more rows and columns there you might want to look at changing the format of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Modify that `for` to:

```
//THIS ONE 
for (title in obj.row.col){
    $('.col-10.title').text(obj.row.col[title]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by nesting for loops.

```js
var json = '{"row":{"col":{"title":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit"}}}'

$(document).ready(function() {
 var obj = JSON.parse(json);
 mainDivData(obj);
  
  function mainDivData(obj) {  
   for (var row in obj){ 
     for(var col in obj[row]) {
        var title = obj[row][col].title;
        $('.col-10 .title').text(title);
      }
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="hero" style="background-image: url(./images/hero.png)">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row row-big">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <h1 class="title">test
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row-small">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="title">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                        consectetur adipiscing elit
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!--Icon missing instead of img--><button type="button" class="btn" style="background-image: url ('./images/button_arrow_white.png')">Sign up now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the first problem was `('.col-10 .title')` ... I didn't have the space between two classes. The second problem was that i was going to far into the loop.

```
for (i in obj.row.col){
            $('.col-10 .title').text(obj.row.col[i]);
        }
```

This solved the problem.